# Devise throwing MySQL error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have Devise installed to manage my Users and it seemed like everything was working fine a couple days ago, except today I get this error:

> > Unknown column 'users.password' in 'where clause

I don't know why Devise is doing thing, any ideas would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the answer, I had password defined as a key and it was causing devise to throw an error.